# How does one access properties within a nested array and object data structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

How can I access properties within a nested array and object data structure.

I wish to access the data within the `sub` property of the object. However as you can see the sub property values do feature objects as well. So here is my code where I am using loop to access the property within this objects which would look something like this as shown below:

```
[{
  updateTime: '2021-08-01T10:31:12.997Z',
  state: 'PUBLISHED',
  description: '[Assignment Link]',
  creationTime: '2021-08-01T10:00:32.502Z',
  creatorUserId: '100720723991781953762',
  maxPoints: 100,
  assigneeMode: 'ALL_STUDENTS',
  title: 'Chapter 10 - Challenge - Sounds',
  topicId: '371133499749',
  dueTime: {
    hours: 12,
    minutes: 29
  },
  courseId: '359355912330',
  dueDate: {
    year: 2021,
    day: 2,
    month: 8
  },
  submissionModificationMode: 'MODIFIABLE_UNTIL_TURNED_IN',
  alternateLink: 'Links',
  id: '375299410585',
  workType: 'ASSIGNMENT',
  sub: {
    '101319245169270376329': [Object],
    '113602874081893916075': [Object],
    '109482297400381284245': [Object],
    '116018616608318973354': [Object],
    '113664444807142890993': [Object],
    '114971581068847820301': [Object],
    '102115961232295542434': [Object],
    '101379903617328602973': [Object],
    '110645572827894944226': [Object],
    '116196654365604694016': [Object],
    '111060187005391455662': [Object],
    '109231821126887264833': [Object],
    '111638802824371384480': [Object],
    '107268429707932588376': [Object],
    '113020667154770187233': [Object],
    '102653891403954041925': [Object],
    '105324491423107091552': [Object],
    '101716831976886159513': [Object],
    '100197750836727383685': [Object],
    '109019166529420617094': [Object],
    '115372484470281534681': [Object],
    '114443976641819242498': [Object]
  }
}]
```

I am trying to access this late and other properties of the object here. Here I am showing you this example by using the following code.

```
console.log(courseWork[0].sub);
```

However when I try to access its sub properties like late or state I am not getting them and I get a  undefined in my console like this:

```
console.log(courseWork[0].sub.late);
```

```
{
  alternateLink: 'Links',
  courseWorkType: 'ASSIGNMENT',
  courseId: '359355912330',
  assignmentSubmission: {},
  userId: '101319245169270376329',
  courseWorkId: '375299410585',
  id: 'Cg0I9eKUzyYQmZXajPYK',
  submissionHistory: [Object],
  state: 'CREATED',
  late: true,
  creationTime: '2021-08-01T10:31:45.071Z',
  updateTime: '2021-08-01T10:31:45.036Z'
}
```

Now I am new at javascript and appscript and never dealt with such big data and objects. How can i access the data to this level.

Comment: Please post sample data as text.

Comment: @Unmitigated sorry my bad will do that now in blockquote format.

Comment: @Unmitigated have made the edit you can see it.

Comment: `console.log(courseWork[0].sub['101319245169270376329'].late)` it should be `true` I think

Comment: @YuriKhristich Thanks for your time Yuri but I am yet getting undefined in the answer by this. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: I am not understanding your question. Your question says you are trying to access a property called `true`?
`console.log(courseWork[0].sub.true);` I don't see a property called `true` in the sample object you have pasted.

Comment: `courseWork[0].sub` is an object. The object has the properties like: `'101319245169270376329'`, `113602874081893916075`, etc. Every the property contains some object. But I can't understand how the second sample  of your data/colde linked with first one.

Comment: @abhinav Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I made a typo error. I am trying to access late here. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @YuriKhristich I am getting value from google classroom api. The code bring me the value from classroom coursework. What you are seeing in the sub section are actually student id and those student id has a record of who submited the data late. IF they submitted late it is true or false. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I tried to use them but not able to get the desired result. Could you point me to direction where I can utilize them to get to the output I wish to get. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Please consult documentations to [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) ... an approach then might contain something like ... `Object.values(courseWork[0].sub)[0].late` for e.g. accessing the first object values' `late` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
        updateTime: '2021-08-01T10:31:12.997Z',
        state: 'PUBLISHED',
        description: '[Assignment Link]',
        creationTime: '2021-08-01T10:00:32.502Z',
        creatorUserId: '100720723991781953762',
        maxPoints: 100,
        assigneeMode: 'ALL_STUDENTS',
        title: 'Chapter 10 - Challenge - Sounds',
        topicId: '371133499749',
        dueTime: {
            hours: 12,
            minutes: 29
        },
        courseId: '359355912330',
        dueDate: {
            year: 2021,
            day: 2,
            month: 8
        },
        submissionModificationMode: 'MODIFIABLE_UNTIL_TURNED_IN',
        alternateLink: 'Links',
        id: '375299410585',
        workType: 'ASSIGNMENT',
        sub: {
            '101319245169270376329': {
                alternateLink: 'Links',
                courseWorkType: 'ASSIGNMENT',
                courseId: '359355912330',
                assignmentSubmission: {},
                userId: '101319245169270376329',
                courseWorkId: '375299410585',
                id: 'Cg0I9eKUzyYQmZXajPYK',
                submissionHistory: {},
                state: 'CREATED',
                late: true,
                creationTime: '2021-08-01T10:31:45.071Z',
                updateTime: '2021-08-01T10:31:45.036Z'
              },
            '113602874081893916075': {},
            '109482297400381284245': {},
            '116018616608318973354': {},
            '113664444807142890993': {},
            '114971581068847820301': {},
            '102115961232295542434': {},
            '101379903617328602973': {},
            '110645572827894944226': {},
            '116196654365604694016': {},
            '111060187005391455662': {},
            '109231821126887264833': {},
            '111638802824371384480': {},
            '107268429707932588376': {},
            '113020667154770187233': {},
            '102653891403954041925': {},
            '105324491423107091552': {},
            '101716831976886159513': {},
            '100197750836727383685': {},
            '109019166529420617094': {},
            '115372484470281534681': {},
            '114443976641819242498': {}
        }
    };

console.log(obj.sub['101319245169270376329'].late); // output: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Yuri. Will give it a try and get back to you if it works out.

Comment: Just with a slide modification the answer you suggest works Yuri. Thank you for your time. I needed to change my code to this for it to work.  console.log(courseWork[0].sub['101319245169270376329'][0].late); Though I accept your answer.

Comment: This is exactly about how the parts of the samples of your data were joined: `sub:{'123':{}}` or `sub:'{123':[{}]}`. It was not quite clear from the question.

Comment: My bad if I  was not able to explain it in proper way. thanks for your time though Yuri.

Answer (score 2):

Please consult documentations to [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) ...

```js
var obj = {
  sub: {
    '101319245169270376329': { late: true },
    '113602874081893916075': { late: true },
    '109482297400381284245': { late: false },
    '116018616608318973354': { late: true },
    '113664444807142890993': { late: true },
    '114971581068847820301': { late: false },
    '102115961232295542434': { late: true },
    '101379903617328602973': { late: false },
  }
};

Object
  .entries(obj.sub)
  .forEach(([key, value]) =>
    console.log(`'${ key }' ... late: ${ value.late }`)
  );
Object
  .values(obj.sub)
  .forEach(item => console.log(`late: ${ item.late }`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Will get back to you as well after trying it and if it seems a good answer too. Thanks for spending your time on it.